# Bounds for volume integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I'm working through some practice problems on volume integrals while preparing for an exam, and I don't understand the bounds in one of them. Here's the prompt in the textbook:

> Find the volume of the region bounded by $z=x+y, 0\leq x\leq 7, 0 \leq y\leq 7$, and the planes $x=0, y=0$, and $z=0$.

I know (from the solutions manual and my professor) that the answer is given by  $\int_0^7\int_0^{7-x}\int_0^{x+y} dzdydx$ (and they don't explain why), but why is $7-x$ the upper bound for $y$? I thought it would be just $7$.

Edit: I am aware that the bounds for x and y on this integral give us a triangle in the first quadrant of the xy-plane with the axes and the line y=7-x as its sides, so maybe I should have been more specific with **my question**:

> How could my professor and the solutions manual be interpreting the instructions (especially the inequalities) to get the triangle and not the square on the xy-plane?

Comment: I don't understand how this even describes a bounded region.

Comment: Yes, and the $z$-limit should be $x+y$.

Comment: @Ted yes, that was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. If your math prof is indeed competent for their job, you should insist and bug them to explain why they have this answer. Did you really ask?

Answer (score 1):

For $[0,7]\times [0,7]$ in $OXY$ plane with roof $z=x+y$, floor $z=0$ volume is
$$\int\limits_0^7\int\limits_0^{7}\int\limits_0^{x+y} dzdydx$$
**Addition 1.**
this integral corresponds exactly to
$$\left\{\begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 7 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant 7 \\
0 \leqslant z \leqslant x+y
\end{array}\right\}$$
which is in OP and **is exactly answer to OP** and is volume over whole rectangle, not only it's lower triangle .

**Addition 2.**
If we want to have volume over triangle, then it is set:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 7 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant 7-x \\
0 \leqslant z \leqslant x+y
\end{array}\right\}$$
so integral will be
$$\int\limits_0^7\int\limits_0^{7-x}\int\limits_0^{x+y} dzdydx$$
excuse me for repeating, that it is not initial OP.

Comment: No, my professor says the answer is what I wrote in the prompt. The solutions manual for the textbook says so too.

Comment: Can you share your textbook, solution manual names? Or solution written by your professor? From one hand you can consider the triangle $\{ 0 \leqslant x  \leqslant 7, 0 \leqslant  y  \leqslant 7-x \}$ and take volume over it, but it is different exercise. What you wrote $[0,7]\times [0,7]$ is different and is in my answer. And remember, that error can be everywhere.

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome, especially when answer is correct.

Comment: Sharing the solution wouldn't help because it literally starts with "the volume is given by the following integral" and then spends a few lines solving it. It's difficult for me to believe both my professor and the solutions manual are wrong; I think the question is very unclear (and my professor agrees), and I'm hoping to get an answer that interprets the question in a way that fits the solution I was given. The key is probably not interpreting the inequalities as specifying a cube, but I don't know what else they could mean or, as you said, where the triangle on the xy-plane comes from.

Comment: @befip. I am sorry, but to be a professor or to be a manual does not help mistake. In mathematics we have more appropriate way to check truth - it is mathematical proof. Do not believe anybody(me also). Everything comes from conditions of task: if/when you want volume over rectangle it is first in my answer, when triangle, then second. I already added both variants, to my answer. And both are correct. To make final decision you should look at page with formulation of task (can you make photo and attach here?)

Comment: What I wrote in the question is word-for-word what the textbook says as the instructions for the problem; I agree with you that it looks like it should be over the square, not the triangle, but I want to know how my professor and the manual are interpreting the instructions so that it's over the triangle, even if it is a strange or "incorrect" interpretation.

Comment: If we speak only about volumes, then difference is clear - you have this fact. Is it possible that some other additional condition is implicitly meant? And, may be, simply ask your professor directly?

Comment: I am dumbfounded why this answer had a score of minus 1 when I stumbled upon it. As indicated in a comment above "to be a professor or to be a manual does not help mistake." @befip In your OP you say: "I know (from the solutions manual and my professor) that the answer is given by ... (and they don't explain why)". Do you mean that *your professor* won't explain why? What kind of professor is that?! Does he just blindly believe the solutions manual, and is afraid to say that the manual is wrong (and just not sure of himself and his math ability and competence to take this step on his/her own)?

Comment: Thanks,  @Mirko.